# Awk null data option

Tags: null, awk, grep

With `grep`, you have a `--null-data` option

```
-z, --null-data           a data line ends in 0 byte, not newline
```

In this way a line is a string ending with a null character, instead of a newline. Does `awk` have a similar option?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `RS` (the record separator) to change how `awk` views lines.  This would be set in a similar manner to the field separator `FS`.  Depending on the version of `awk` you are using you may be able to set this to NULL.

For example,

```
awk '{ print $0 }' RS="\0" file
```

Note that this may [not be portable](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Records.html) if you are not using the GNU awk implementation.

Answer (score 0):

With awk, you can use `printf` :

```
awk '/regex/{printf("%s\n\0", $0)}'
```